# Rule to express that n predicates should be true

Tags: logic

Given an arbitrarily big set of predicates {p1 .. pn}. Is there a way to build a rule or set of them to express that a number n of them have to be true?. So far I can only imagine to make all posible permutations of the valid conjunctions like for n=2 {p1^p2^-p3}, {-p1^p2^p3}, {p1^-p2^p3}.

Answer (score 0):

One could write something like $|\{p \in P: p \text{  true}\}| \geq n$. But it is probably more intelligible to just write "at least $n$ of the formulas in $P$ should be true".

Comment: Sorry, I was asking for some actual algorithm using propositional logic formulas to check that truth value.

Comment: In that case, you have to reformulate your question. You were asking for a way to "express" it, not "compute" it.